# Debian NAS server - how to achieve zero disk activity

Tags: debian, hard-drive, samba, nas

I want to prolong the lifespan of my hard drives in my NAS server so I want them to be completely idle when nobody actively uses NAS services. However because of logging and RAID 1 sync I can hear my drives spinning during the night.

How can I setup my Debian to let the drives in idle mode as long as nobody actively uses samba ?

iotop:

```
  root@NAS:~# iotop
Total DISK READ:         0.00 B/s | Total DISK WRITE:        76.28 K/s
Current DISK READ:       0.00 B/s | Current DISK WRITE:     166.87 K/s
  TID  PRIO  USER     DISK READ  DISK WRITE  SWAPIN     IO>    COMMAND
  283 be/3 root        0.00 B/s   61.03 K/s  0.00 %  3.30 % [jbd2/md0-8]
  598 be/4 root        0.00 B/s   15.26 K/s  0.00 %  0.00 % rsyslogd -n -iNONE [rs:main Q:Reg]
    1 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % init
    2 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [kthreadd]
    3 be/0 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [rcu_gp]
```

Comment: Why do I believe that ? Maybe because the drives will be idle for 12 hours during the night ? If the uptime of the drives will be half, they will last longer. If there would be no activity then there wont be any spin ups during the night.

Comment: @vidarlo and no, NASes are not off topic here, see the tags please.

Comment: In a home environment they *are* offtopic. In a business environment, they are not off topic.

Comment: Your assumption about idle drives getting longer lifespan is wrong. If the question is about getting quiet drives during the night, then the question is valid, in a home setting, but not business. Use superuser instead.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your contention that drives are better turned off when not in use for longevity reasons is dubious at best.

You can use the hdparm command to control the drive sleep level.   If you want to force the drive off you can likely use "-Y" option, but you will need to then wake it manually.     You most likely want to use hdparm -S to put the drive into idle mode when not required.  The man page says this about -S :

> -S     Put the drive into idle (low-power) mode, and also set the standby (spindown) timeout for the drive.  This timeout value  is used
> by the  drive  to determine how long to wait (with no disk activity)
> before turning off the spindle motor to save power.  Under such
> circumstances, the drive may take as long as 30 seconds to respond to
> a subsequent disk access, though most drives are much quicker.  The
> encoding  of the timeout value is somewhat peculiar.  A value of zero
> means "timeouts are disabled": the device will not automatically enter
> standby mode.  Values from 1 to 240 specify multiples of 5 seconds,
> yielding timeouts from 5 seconds to 20 minutes.  Values from 241 to
> 251 specify from 1 to 11 units of 30 minutes, yielding timeouts from
> 30 minutes to 5.5 hours.  A value of 252 signifies a time‐out of 21
> minutes. A value of 253 sets a vendor-defined timeout period between 8
> and 12 hours, and the value 254 is reserved. 255  is interpreted as 21
> minutes plus 15 seconds.  Note that some older drives may have very
> different interpretations of these values.

Comment: Why they are "dubious at best" when I had synology NAS it was configured automatically to put the drives into idle mode, then it took about 5 secs when accessing the drives for the first time since they went into idle.

Comment: @welite you can Google this yourself, but an important  argument against spinning the drives up frequently are that this puts a lot of stress on the drive.  There may also be arguments relating to rate of expansion/contraction due to temp differences.  It seems that many consumer NAS's are worried about noise and power ratings - spun down drives make these figures look better.